# Java/Scala library to load font file and generate draw commands

Tags: java, scala, fonts

Is there a java or scala library which can load a font file (ttf, otf, etc) and provide enough information to actually draw the font, including things like kerning? It should also provide information about the font such as the weight, whether or not it is italic, whether it is serif or sans-serif, etc.

Currently we are using cufon as an external process, which works most of the time, but has some problems.

Comment: I take it AWT font support is not sufficient? You can read TTF and draw them using Java2D.

Comment: Ultimately, I need to produce a JSON file that contains SVG draw commands for each glyph, as well as some other information. I might be able to use AWT fonts and Java2D, but I don't know how I would do that.

Comment: I would google for Java+Font+Editor. Anyway, you can get the `GlyphVector` stuff via Java2D, and you could export using something like Apache Batik or JFree SVGGraphics2D.

Comment: I also need a way get all of the kerning pairs from the font, and it doesn't look like there is a way to do that with Java2D.